# How to find a reference that is 'to be published'?

Tags: soft-question

How to find the references in the papers looks like e.g. that:

> P.Moller, J.R.Nix and W.J.Swiatecki, Proc. Winter Workshop on nuclear dynamics V, SunValley, Idaho, 1988, *to be published*.

When I encountered this kind of reference before, I always gave up. But this reference seems important for me now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not ask about physics or a physics concept; rather, it asks the users to search for a paper.

Comment: @Yashas, this kind of question appears when you read a paper. I am not asking someone to offer this reference, but I am asking the method to find such kind of 'to be published' papers that were mentioned in their articles.

Comment: You could use the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: Physics.SE is about the science of physics as such, not about things that might come up in the academic life of a physicist. Insofar as there is an SE site for that, it is [academia.SE], but I don't know whether they would consider this question on-topic or not - you could try, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually putting title and authors in a search gives a handle . putting "P.Moller, J.R.Nix and W.J.Swiatecki, Proc. Winter Workshop on nuclear dynamics V, SunValley, Idaho, 1988" I got a number of references.

Then looking in there one can find a reference if the authors exist in later papers, since usually people keep on working on the same lines.

I found [this reference,](http://t2.lanl.gov/nis/molleretal/publications/fdsmmanus.pdf) and searching it one sees a number of entries for the first author, which are references to published papers.

You can continue from those.

Comment: you mean that maybe this reference is not published when their paper are published, but that reference may appear in some other papers their will publish in the future, and I can find them from the latter papers. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you need to put the subject in the search, and at least one of the authors. If it exists it can be dug out.

Comment: @zmwang, it means that Moller et al. had submitted their paper and shared it with the guy who referenced it. But the proceedings hadn't been published yet, so s/he couldn't include some details (like page numbers) in the citation. If you can find the "Proc. Winter Workshop on nuclear dynamics V" in your library you should find the paper in the table of contents and be able to read it (and cite it with all details).

Comment: @ThePhoton of course if one has an access to a real library that is the first thing to do for old references.  This particular seems to have been printed. https://indico.cern.ch/event/555216/page/7594-previous-workshopsMy answer is of trying to find a link on the  web.